# Number of distinct integer-valued vector solution for $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations, combinations

**The Number Of Integer Solutions Of Equations $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$$**

An approach is to find the number of distinct **non-negative** integer-valued vectors $(x_1,x_2,...,x_r)$ such that $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$$

There are $n+r-1\choose r-1$ distinct **non-negative** integer-valued vectors $(x_1, x_2,...,x_r)$ satisfying the equation $$ x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n $$

So there are $n+r-1\choose r-1$ solutions.

**My question is how to count number of solutions for above equation considering all vectors whose permutation is same.**

Now consider for $n = 2$ and $r = 2$
solutions are {(0,2), (2,0), (1,1)} 
as we can see (0,1) is a permutation of (1,0),  so count them only once.

Therefore total number of solutions for $n = 2$ and $r = 2$ is 2 instead of 3.

Comment: We are counting the number of partitions  of $n$ into at most $r$ parts, which is the number of partitions of $n+r$ into exactly $r$ parts. You can find a lot of information by searching for these terms. There are useful recurrences, a nice generating function, and good asymptotics, but no "closed form."

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the solution.

Comment: Your use of "distinct" is ambiguous here: some may read $1+1$ as not allowed as the $1$s have the same value as each other

Comment: Yeah,  I can see that.